# Codeigniter Mail - I had it working, and now it's not. Tell me why?

Tags: codeigniter, email

Just trying to set up an AJAX contact form in Codeigniter.  It's my first time using CI.

I had it working, and now it's broke and I'm not sure why.

Here is the code..

The JS

```
$.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: post_url,
        data: post_data,
        beforeSend:function(){
            alert(this.data);  <<< This is alerting the correct form data to me
        },
        success:function(msg){
            $($form).fadeOut(500, function(){
                var msg = '<div class="messageSent"><p>'+ msg +'</p></div>';
                $form.html(msg).fadeIn();  <<< This is returning undefined
            });
        }
    });
```

.. and the PHP ...

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Email extends CI_Controller{


 public function __construct()
   {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('email');
   }



public function index(){

$emailFromName = $this->input->post('name', TRUE);
$emailFromAddress = html_entity_decode($this->input->post('email', TRUE));
$emailFromMessage = "Email from the Brewer's website\n";
$emailFromMessage .= "==============================\n";
$emailFromMessage .= "From: " + $emailFromName + "\n";
$emailFromMessage .= "==============================\n";
$emailFromMessage .= "Respond Email; " + $emailFromAddress +"\n";
$emailFromMessage .= "==============================\n";
$emailFromMessage .= $this->input->post('message', TRUE);


$this->email->from($emailFromName);
$this->email->to('recipient@gmail.com'); 
$this->email->subject('Message from the website.');
$this->email->message($emailFromMessage);   

$this->email->send();

echo $this->email->print_debugger();  // echoes undefined
// echo($emailFromName);  // also echoes undefined
}
}

?>
```

I think the problem must be in the PHP.. it just doesn't seem to be reading any of the posted variables.  I cant even echo $this->input->post('name');  (Although I had it working!)

.. so what am I doing wrong?

NOTE - I put the html_entity_decode in there because I noticed the email addy was getting posted as "address%40gmail.com"... so it seemed like a good idea.  Is it necessary?

Comment: Well, the obvious question: What have you changed since it worked?

Comment: are you autoloading the email library?  Also, did you verify via console that the ajax part is actually sending the right data and also  not throwing an error?  also, if it is, did you change hosts or something recently and perhaps theres a 302 clearing out your post data?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Ha.  Roughly 57 to 83.5 small things.  None of which should have affected mail!

Comment: @JohnB  Yes I am autoloading mail.  And Ajax is sending the right data... I alert it just before I send.  Its good (aside from the @ in the emailAddress being encoded which I mention)

Comment: hmmm have you tried just var_dumping the post array there and exiting?  also, tried just var dumping the result of the email send function?  Also, might not be effecting you but a lot of hosting companies have an spf policy that the way your contact form is set up would end up returning true on the send function but not eactually ever be sent be because of blocking by the servers internal spam filter.  it will have to come from the domain the code is hosted on.

Comment: @JohnB  I'm thinking you might be right.  The mail was sending when I had the site on my testing server.  When I uploaded it to the client server the mail broke (although the cause and effect were distant from another).  I also had to get the PHP updated from .. like.. 4 point something.  BUT when I alert the content of my onSuccess message I get UNDEFINED no matter what I try to return.. even if its just the "name" I posted over.  Wouldn't I at least be able to echo *something* from PHP back out to AJAX.. even if the mail was getting blocked?

Comment: it depends. You could just echo out 'test' instead of a post variable to answer that question.  If that works then you may have an htaccess issue causing a post clearing redirect.  Usually you can fix something like that by making sure the www is in the post url, or not in etc.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, this is not an answer for your question- but I struggled greatly with stabilizing my CodeIgniter project's mail feature.  The solution I found took about 1 hour to implement, and it has saved me 10 hours of trouble, I'm sure.

Consider sending mail from your application with the "SwiftMailer" framework.  It is a powerful reliable php mail framework, and it's free.  At first I had a hard time integrating the 2 frameworks, then I found this blog, I had the task done in minutes.

http://grafikkaos.co.uk/blog/article/101-using-swift-mailer-with-codeigniter

Comment: Thanks.  I have used Swift mailer before.. but I honestly thought CI would allow me to leave that behind.  In your troubleshooting did you find that CI's mail is troublesome for many people?  Seems strange that such a "big feature" would be broken in CI.